# Maximum file size for polymer build?

Tags: build, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to build my app, so I ran the following command:

```
polymer build -v
```

In the terminal print out, I see the following message:

> debug: Skipping static resource "build/bundled/src/path/to/my-element.html" (2.46 MB) - max size is 2.1 MB

There are also console errors originating from the same file when I serve the bundled version with:

```
polymer serve build/bundled
```

*console log:*

> my-element.html:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
>
> my-element.html:1280 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashToCamelCase' of undefined

Is there a maximum file size for `polymer build`? If so, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no file size limit that would cause those errors.

That message is from [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/776b059/lib/sw-precache.js#L183), which has a [default max file size of 2MB](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#maximumfilesizetocacheinbytes-number). The warning indicates that the file won't be precached by the service worker, and this should not cause any runtime errors in your app. The errors you pointed out are unlikely related to this warning.